# Real function with categoric domain. Is it possible?

Tags: functions, definition

First we are going to look through what a function is:

Take $A$ and $B$ to be a set, a function $f$ is an operator such that $f:A\rightarrow B $ that is a function will map an element from $A$ and the result of this mapping will be setted on $B$.

Now take  $A$ to be a categorical set for example $A=\{'yes','no' \}$, Is it possible to define a function $f: A \rightarrow \Re$ without applying any previous transformation on $A$ (for example a dummy coding)? . It's more than clean that it can't be get by algebra (using polynomials, sin, cos, ln, etc) but could I just define (as an exemple of this kind of function):

$f('yes')=5.2$

$f('no')=2.4$ ?

Note that I've defined $f$ as an operator such that $f('yes')=5.2$ and $f('no')=2.4$ so I think the why $f('yes')=5.2$ wouldn't matter at all I just have defined as it and I guess that's enough.

Either, Am I wrong and should I define $f$ with some algebrical structure to map its domain to real set? or It all is enough and there is no wrong math on it?

PS: This trouble comes from trying to go decision trees as a function since this algorithm can map categorical to real.

Comment: There's no problem... what you said defines a function from $\{'yes', 'no'\}$ to $\mathbb R.$ Usually the definition of a function doesn't say anything about 'transforming'. It says a function $A\to B$ is a set of pairs $(a,b)$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that each $a$ appears exactly once in the set, i.e. each input has a unique output associated with it. So in this case $f=\{('yes', 5.2), ('no', 2.4)\}$

Comment: Also, even for more transformation-based interpretations of what a function is, this is fine... e.g. you can easily write a computer program that implements it.

Comment: Sorry I misused that word so I've replaced it as 'map'. Yeah, I thought it'd hold but I haven't ever seen any discussion about this so I just wanted to be sure. We now that the math can be pretty more complex than it's supposed to be. I think you be better posting your comment as answer even if it's pretty simple.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen seconding that your comments could make an answer